# Writing ggplot secondary axis formula correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need a secondary axis in R ggplot2 and can't get the formula right.
I could not find a similar question answered in Google searches.
This is what works:

---

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                 y = c(20, 55, 69, 72, 73, 72))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(shape = 21,size = 5,color = "black",fill = "orange",stroke = 1) +
scale_x_continuous(name = 'Number of Contacts') +
scale_y_continuous(name="Remembered (%)", 
sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~. +10,name = "Remembered (Index)"))
```

[image: orginal]
However, my formula in the sec_axis part is more complicated and should be something like

```
secondary axis =  (y - min(y)) * 100/(max(y)- min(y))
```

so secondary axis would be

```
c(0.00000,  66.03774,  92.45283,  98.11321, 100.00000,  98.11321)
```

in this example. The idea is to have an index on the right of the diagram 
that allows to find the 70-80% range of given values.

I tried different versions of `I()` but in vain. 
Any ideas are welcome. Also any document explaining the formula part of the function more thoroughly
would be welcome. ?formula did not help me much in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` in formula is your `y`. You only have to replace in your formula the `y` by a `.`.

The formula becomes :

```
~ (.-min(.))*100/(max(.)-min(.))
```

In your example it gives you :

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                     y = c(20, 55, 69, 72, 73, 72))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21,size = 5,color = "black",fill = "orange",stroke = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Number of Contacts') +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Remembered (%)", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ (.-min(.))*100/(max(.)-min(.)),
                                         name = "Remembered (Index)"))
```

Comment: If you wan more information for formula in R : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, that's exactly what I was looking for. From the ?formula information it was not clear to me that . is a symbol for the primary y axis. Your explanation is much clearer.

Comment: Hi @Blockhuette if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

something like this,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% mutate(y2 = (y -min(y))* 100/(max(y)- min(y))) %>%  
   ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y2)) + 
        geom_point(shape = 21,size = 5,color = "black",fill = "orange",stroke = 1) + 
        scale_x_continuous(name = 'Number of Contacts') + 
        scale_y_continuous(name="Remembered (%)", 
     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~. +10,name = "Remembered (Index)"))
```

[image: yha]

Comment: Thanks for this solution! However, I need both scales: original values AND transformed values in one graph.

Comment: I realized I diden't read your question correctly. I take Thomas' answer above answers your question.